# Angular JS form data post to Jersey method is giving null on Query Parameter

Tags: angularjs, jersey, http-post

I was just playing around doing some testing, here is some Javascript, that uses Angular JS to post some form data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Add a course</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../angular.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="form">
        <div ng-controller="formController">
            <form class="course-form">
                Name: <input type="text" ng-model="course.name" /><br />
                Duration: <input type="text" ng-model="course.duration" /><br />
                Fee: <input type="text" ng-model="course.fee" /><br />
                <input type="button" ng-click="add(course)" value="Add course" />
            </form>
        </div>

    <script>
        angular.module('form', [])
            .controller('formController', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', function($scope, $http, $log) {

                $scope.add = function(courseData) {
                    var url = "http://localhost:8080/CourseService/courseService/newcourse";

                    var request = $http({method: 'POST', url: url, data:{name: courseData.name, duration: courseData.duration, fee: courseData.fee}});

                    request.success(
                        function(html) {
                            alert("it succeeded");
                        }
                    );

                    request.error(
                        function(html) {
                            alert("it didn't work");
                        }
                    );

                };
        }]);
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

here is the method that the data is posted to:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/newcourse")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response newCourse(@QueryParam("name") String name, @QueryParam("duration") String duration, @QueryParam("fee") int fee) {

        System.out.println(name+""+duration+""+fee);
        return Response.status(200).build();

    }
```

The problem is that When I print the values, they are all null except for the fee which is 0, is there a reason why this is? I have checked the values being posted and they are fine and populated.

I did have other ways or writing the above service method, such as using `@FormData`, I could also have changed the path to be: `("/newcourse/{name}/{duration}/{fee}"), and URI encoding the values in, but this is just the way I ended up testing it.

Comment: I noticed the same behavior in my server side. I could not get POST or GET parameter sent by `$http`. I do not know what is there in example,  but try to get request body. That should be a json. And check browser inspector what it does send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the data to be received as query params, (i.e. the requested URL will be like `http://localhost:8080/CourseService/courseService/newcourse?name=123&duration=456&fee=789`) you have to send them using the `params` option, instead of the `data`, which specifies the request body:

```
var request = $http({method: 'POST', url: url,
    params:{name: courseData.name, duration: courseData.duration, fee: courseData.fee}});
```

Comment: Thank you, I did some more playing around with it and found way to work, I have to admit though, when I annotate the method as POST using this way I get a no Access-Control-ALlow-Origin header is present error, but when I use GET I don't see the problem, I have CORS handling in my web.xml, but I don't see why I get this with POST and not GET